# Paw cURL Import change \ to %5C

Tags: curl, paw-app

Importing a `cURL` command:

```
curl -k https://X.X.X.X:3000/mo/dns?server=192.168.0.10\&suffix=domain.local\&filter=applicationname
```

into PAW changes it to:

```
curl "https://X.X.X.X:3000/mo/dns?server=192.168.0.10%5C&suffix=domain.local%5C&filter=applicationname"
```

I'm then getting an errror response from the destination server:

> {"error":{"message":"Failed to execute WF."}}

I have tried changing the PAW HTTP Libraries

This might not be an error, but may be expected, could also be the destination API server that should have a change made to it. Hoping someone has some insight on this.

Also when I do the generic `cURL` call before the import into PAW, all works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my own problem, PAW uses URL encoding by default, you can change it under the URL Params tab, and change the value / values to be interpreted as a "Raw query string" , PAW will then incldued the %5C in the rraw encoding, change it to \

then

200 OK